# Django, Overriding behavior Admin Model

Tags: django, django-admin

in the django admin, in any app model, the diplay data (datagrid o view template, i dont know how call it), django show "all" the entry, but what happen if i want that django just show the entry with statu live or x status and not all entry with any status?.

how, overriding initial behavior in admin model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/django-admin-filter) with some answers.