# Django admin default filter

Tags: django, django-admin

I know I already managed to do this but can't remember how nor I can't find any documentation about this..

How can apply a filter by default on a object list view in the admin ?

I have an app which list quotes and those quotes have a status (ex: accepted, rejected, on hold ..).

I want the filter set on status='accepted' by default that is..

Comment: Just for the record this question [is correctly answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin/3783930#3783930)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default filter in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 22):

A bit more reusable approach:

```
class DefaultFilterMixIn(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
        if self.default_filters:
            try:
                test = request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].split(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
                if test and test[-1] and not test[-1].startswith('?'):
                    url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (self.opts.app_label, self.opts.module_name))
                    filters = []
                    for filter in self.default_filters:
                        key = filter.split('=')[0]
                        if not request.GET.has_key(key):
                            filters.append(filter)
                    if filters:                        
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("%s?%s" % (url, "&".join(filters)))
            except: pass
        return super(DefaultFilterMixIn, self).changelist_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And then just define a default_filters on your ModelAdmin:

```
class YourModelAdmin(DefaultFilterMixIn):
    ....
    default_filters = ('snapshot__exact=0',)
```

Comment: for me (which might be different because I'm using django-grappelli) this works BUT only when it's `snapshot=0` and not `snapshot__exact=0` and also, for whatever reason, the filters don't work any more and this is because the javascript is broken (console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'actions' ") and again this could be because of grappelli. sorry for the run-on sentence, lol.

Comment: worked just fine for me with django==1.3.4 and grappelli==2.3.9. major props for the mixin.

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, but it doesn’t work with Python 3 and Django 1.9.7. Just silencing the exceptions is not such a good idea, so I commented this out. Then I found that self.opts.module_name should be self.opts.model_name instead and “`request.GET.has_key(key)`”: has been replaced by “`key in request.GET`”: (updated code too long to be accepted here)

Comment: `self.opts.module_name` must be replaced by `self.opts.model_name` according to Django>=1.8. Release note: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/
__Model._meta.module_name was renamed to model_name.__

Answer (score 8):

Finally, this is what I was looking for:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    if not request.GET.has_key('status__exact'):
        q = request.GET.copy()
        q['status__exact'] = '1'
        request.GET = q
        request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = request.GET.urlencode()
    return super(SoumissionAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

The other way, with the queryset method in the admin class does not work. In fact it does filter the results, but it leaves the filter functionality broken.

The solution I've found is not perfect either, it's not possible when using it to select the "All/ filter. In my case it's not dramatic and it will be good enough though..

Comment: has_key function has been deprecated after v1.8

Answer (score 7):

You can override the queryset

```
class QuoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(QuoteAdmin,self).get_queryset(request).filter(status="accepted")
```

However by overriding the queryset you won't ever be able to view quotes that do not have status "accepted".

Alternatively, you can link to the following URL, adding the filter to the GET parameters.

```
/admin/myapp/quote/?status=accepted
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem with support 'all'.

in models.py:

```
STATUSES_CHOICE = (
    ('0', 'Active'),
    ('1', 'Deactive'),
    ('2', 'Suspended'),
)

class Client(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Status'),
                                 default=0,
                                 db_index=True)
```

in admin.py:

```
class StatusAdminFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Status')
    parameter_name = 'status'
    all_param_value = 'all'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return STATUSES_CHOICE

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        status = self.value()
        try:
            return (queryset if status == self.all_param_value else
                    queryset.filter(status=int(status)))
        except ValueError:
            raise Http404

    def choices(self, cl):
        yield {'selected': self.value() == self.all_param_value,
               'query_string': cl.get_query_string(
                   {self.parameter_name: self.all_param_value}, 
                   [self.parameter_name]),
               'display': _('All')}
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {'selected': self.value() == lookup,
                   'query_string': cl.get_query_string(
                       {self.parameter_name: lookup}, []),
                   'display': title}


class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (StatusAdminFilter,)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.GET.has_key('status'):
            q = request.GET.copy()
            q['status'] = '0'  # default value for status
            request.GET = q
            request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = request.GET.urlencode()
        return super(ClientAdmin, self).changelist_view(
            request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Thank goodness. I could not find a way to remove "All". Everyone else said you just left it out in the "lookups" function. In actual fact you needed to leave it out in the "choices" function

Answer (score 6):

Short and clean solution. Works nice with "All" option when clicked on change list view.

```
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.META['QUERY_STRING'] and \
            not request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '').startswith(request.build_absolute_uri()):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path + "?status__exact=1")
        return super(YourModelAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a way to do this without limiting the user. Just look at the referer to determine if the user just arrived at this page. If so redirect them to the default url you want based on that filter.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    try:
        test = request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].split(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
        if test and test[-1] and not test[-1].startswith('?') and not request.GET.has_key('status__exact'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/app/model/?status__exact=1")
    except: pass # In case there is no referer
    return super(MyModelAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: It's quite the hard-coded hack, but this answer works. I made it just the slightest less-hackish by replacing "/admin/app/model/" with request.path and concatenated my equivalent of "?status__exact=1" to it before sending the http response redirect

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and avoided having the "All" problem mentioned by h3.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
    showall = request.META['PATH_INFO'] in referer and not request.GET.has_key('timeframe')
    if not showall and not request.GET.has_key('param_name_here'):
        q = request.GET.copy()
        q['param_name_here'] = 'default_value_here'
        request.GET = q
        request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = request.GET.urlencode()
    return super(SerializableAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my update for glic3rinu's code (see comment there), which works on Python 3.4 and Django 1.9.7:

```
class DefaultFilterMixIn(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
        if self.default_filters:
            #try:
                test = request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].split(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
                if test and test[-1] and not test[-1].startswith('?'):
                    url = reverse('admin:{}_{}_changelist'.format(self.opts.app_label, self.opts.model_name))
                    filters = []
                    for filter in self.default_filters:
                        key = filter.split('=')[0]
                        if not key in request.GET:
                            filters.append(filter)
                    if filters:                     
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("{}?{}".format(url, "&".join(filters)))
            #except: pass
        return super(DefaultFilterMixIn, self).changelist_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: HTTP_REFERER will not always exist (or be relevant), neither will REQUEST_URI apparently (I don't know how but I don't have it)... I don't see a safe way to know when a ? is present in the URL otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to have a default filter set in admin (only tested with Django 1.11):

```
class ZeroCountListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('include zero count')
    parameter_name = 'count'

    def choices(self, changelist):
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() is None or self.value() == 0,
            'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({}, [self.parameter_name]),
            'display': _('No'),
        }
        yield {
            'selected': self.value() == '1',
            'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: '1'}, []),
            'display': _("Yes"),
        }

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('0', _('No')),
            ('1', _('Yes')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() is None or self.value() == '0':
            return queryset.exclude(count=0)
        else:
            return queryset
```

The trick is to check `self.value() is None` to get the default behaviour