# Changing the link for the ModelAdmin list view in Django to apply a default filter?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to apply a default filter value on a field ModelAdmin in django.

I have a Model admin for the `User` model, which displays users. The user has a m2m to an `Account` model, so I am adding in the ModelAdmin:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_filters = ('accounts')
```

In the filter I want it to give a default selected value, if nothing is selected. However I still want to give the user the option to revert to the default `All` option.

So far all the solutions that I found, prevent reverting to the `All` option. For example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3070184/855475).

I am thinking, that maybe chaining the link on the side menu to include the desired filter option in the query parameters. Is this doable? I can see in the source code for  `admin/app_list.html` ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/app_list.html)), that the URL comes from `model.admin_link`, but I cant find any documentation for changing it.

[image]

Comment: i think this may help you with changing `admin_url` of a model class https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420333/11225821

Comment: @LinhNguyen, this seems to be only for retrieving the URL

Comment: actually no, get_ method will trigger when you call that atribute in a class. So get_abc will override the return getter of your_class.abc