# How do I tell my ModelAdmin's filter to not show all records by default?

Tags: python, django

I added a filter drop down in my django admin page like this.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('status',)
```

By default, if you go to the model in the admin view, it displays all records by default.
But I want it to filter:

```
status="open"
```

and display it by default. Is this achievable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin/3783930#3783930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is ModelAdmin.ordering
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering

If you ONLY need status='open' you could have defined a custom default queryset for your modeladmin
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset
and restricted your
list items to be status='open' only. (CAUTION) However in that case other records (status!='open') will become inaccessible from the admin.

Answer (score -1):

If i correct understand, you may redefine default model manager in model

```
    class myManager(models.Manager):
         return self.filter(status = 'open')

    class myModel(models.Model):
         ...
         objects = myManager()
```

But I think there is a more elegant way.