# Default django-admin list filter

Tags: django-admin

My question is just an extension of this thread [Question]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin .

```
from myproject.myapp.mymodels import fieldC


class Poll(models.Model):

    fieldA = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=CHOICES.MyCHOICES) 
    fieldB = models.ForeignKey(fieldC)

admin.py

list_display = ('fieldB__fieldc1')

Now my list filter shows four criteria All, A ,B ,C  .
```

What I want is if the superuser is logged in ,the filter should show all four criteria All,A,B,C and if the user is other than superuser filter should only show All, A, B.

How can i acheive this ?
Here is my actual piece of admin.py

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):

        referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
        test = referer.split(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
        if test[-1] and not test[-1].startswith('?'):
            if not request.GET.has_key('patient__patient_type__exact'):

                q = request.GET.copy()
                q['patient__patient_type__exact'] = 'Real'
                request.GET = q
                request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = request.GET.urlencode()
                if not request.user.is_superuser:
                    q['patient__patient_type__exact'] = 'Real'
    return super(VisitAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)


Thanks in advance
```

Comment: I'm confused whether you are trying to make a *different default filter* for user and su, or a *different set of filter querysets* for user and su?

Comment: I am using the same filter for both superuser and other users.I just want that when superuser logs in he should see all the choices like "Real" , "Test" and "Guest" in the list_filter and he should be able to filter the rows of that table but if user is not superuser the filter should only show "Real" and "Guest" choices in the list_filter and he should only be able to filter the rows for "Real" and "Guest" choices.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new FilterSpec API in Django 1.4 gives you exactly what you need here. [Check out the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) on list_filter. In 1.4 you can now make custom list filters that subclass `django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter` and give you the power to write custom lookup and queryset code, and since the request is passed in you can do a simple conditional with is_superuser.

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
    # pass one set of lookups
else:
    # pass a different set
```

read the example code in the docs carefully and I think it will all be clear.