# default Admin List filter not selected but implemented

Tags: django, filter, admin, default

I have in my admin a list of object representing "Projects" which have filters applied to them. Each "Project" can either be Open or Closed (Defaulting to open). My problem is that the objects are filtered by default but the applied filter option (yes/no) isn't highlighted until manually selected.

I also looked at this but the solution wouldn't work for me:
[Default filter in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin)

EDIT: Added code.

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    save_on_top = True
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "created_at", "updated_at", "region", "get_main", "get_code", related_information]
    list_display_links = ("__unicode__",)
    search_fields = ["short_title_eng"]
    form = ProjectForm
    ordering = ('project_number',)
    change_form_template = "project/project_change_form.html"
    add_form_template = "project/project_add_form.html"
    readonly_fields = ["project_number"]

    list_filter = (ProjectStatusFilter, CountryFilter, RegionFilter, ProjectAEI, ProjectCropType)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('short_title_eng', 'project_number', 'close_project'),
            'classes': ['wide', ],
        }),
```

Comment: Can u give a piece of your code to investigate what u tried?

Comment: I added the code in the question.