# Default Boolean Filter in Django Admin

Tags: django, filter, admin, default

I have seen the solution for a default choice field.  [Default filter in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin)

It's not obvious how to extend that to a boolean field.  I have an archive field that keeps things from being displayed.  I'd like the default filter to be No instead of All.

Answer (score 8):

```
class BooleanDefaultNoFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('all', 'All'),
            (1, 'Yes'),
            (None, 'No')
        )

    def choices(self, changelist):
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                'selected': self.value() == (str(lookup) if lookup else lookup),
                'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: lookup}, []),
                'display': title,
            }

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            if self.value() == 'all':
                return queryset
            else:
                return queryset.filter(**{self.parameter_name: self.value()})

        elif self.value() == None:
            return queryset.filter(**{self.parameter_name: False})

class NamedFilter(BooleanDefaultNoFilter):
    title = _('InsertName')
    parameter_name = 'insertname'

class InsertNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_filters = (NamedFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the filter to show only Yes/No (without All), and to have Yes by default. That way I can avoid some of the confusion for the user to see the All option selected while actually having the Yes filter applied.

I came up with this:

```py
class DefaultYesBooleanFieldListFilter(BooleanFieldListFilter):
    default = "1"

    def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
        super().__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)
        if not self.lookup_val:
            self.lookup_val = self.default
            self.used_parameters[self.lookup_kwarg] = self.default

    def choices(self, changelist):
        choices = super().choices(changelist)
        choices.__next__()
        for choice in choices:
            print(choice)
            yield choice


class DefaultNoBooleanFieldListFilter(DefaultYesBooleanFieldListFilter):
    default = "0"
```

Usage: the same as a normal `BooleanFieldListFilter`, that is,

```py
class SomethingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ("active", DefaultYesBooleanFieldListFilter),
    )
```

Note that users will still have the general link to show all results (or remove all filters) which will still cause some confusion.

I hope it's helpful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

Overriding the `get_queryset` method from [django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) is one way to solve this problem.

This method allows you to specify what object to return when requesting that resource from the admin site.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        # Here's where we specify what to filter our queryset by.
        return qs.filter(archived=False)
```

Comment: This approach works well as a permanent filter.  I have list_filter = ('archive') as well.  I would like to be able to see the archived, I just don't want to see them by default.  Is there a way to pass the filter information into get_queryset?