# How to override empty_label in filter django based in SimpleListFilter?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm making a filter on django based on SimpleListFilter, I would like to know if there is a way to replace the label all in the filter.

I tried ovveride empty string but not works

```py
class IgnoreAttendanceReportFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Aulas ignoradas pelo extrato de frequência'
    parameter_name = 'aula__status__ignore_in_attendance_report'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('yes', 'Sim'),
            ('', 'No'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'yes':
            return queryset.filter(aula__status__ignore_in_attendance_report=True)
        # return queryset
        return queryset.filter(aula__status__ignore_in_attendance_report=False)
```

This way in my display list: all, Yes and No,
I want to change all for No, this way default filter is will be No, and my display only Yes and No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default filter in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851636/default-filter-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 1):

Try to override method **choices**

```py
class IgnoreAttendanceReportFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter): 

    [ ... ]

    def choices(self, changelist):                                              
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:                               
            yield {                                                             
                'selected': self.value() == str(lookup),                        
                'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: lookup}),
                'display': title,                                               
            }
```

Now default value will be False. But in this case No woudn't be mark as selected. If No have to me select if filter is not selected try to use None instead of empty string ale fix method, by remove cast to str. Fixed method bellow.

```py
class IgnoreAttendanceReportFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter): 

    [ ... ]

    def choices(self, changelist):                                              
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:                               
            yield {                                                             
                'selected': self.value() == lookup,                        
                'query_string': changelist.get_query_string({self.parameter_name: lookup}),
                'display': title,                                               
            }
```

If field have default value as False you don't need to filter on them.

Furthermore, if you filter by field from another model necessary use select_related. Otherwise this filter will make a lot of redundant database queries. So if **aula** and **status** are other model try to use something like this.

```py
    [....]
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'yes':
            return queryset.select_related('aula__status').filter(aula__status__ignore_in_attendance_report=True)

        return queryset
```

I hope it works.